# Render data dynamic with rowspan

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-table

I am trying to render table using **ngFor** and **rowspan**  in angular project, this is my data:

```
 list = [
    {
      name: "app1",
      templates:[
        { name: "temp1", version: 1}
      ]
    },
        {
      name: "app2",
      templates:[
        { name: "temp1", version: 1},
        { name: "temp1", version: 2},
        { name: "temp1", version: 3}
      ]
    },
        {
      name: "app3",
      templates:[
        { name: "temp1", version: 1},
         { name: "temp1", version: 2}
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I want to render this data dynamic  like this

[image]

thanks

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple aproach whould be like this

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black">
  <tr>
     <th>Application</th>
     <th>Version</th>
  </tr>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let obj of list">
      <tr *ngFor="let entry of obj.templates;let i = index">
          <td [attr.rowspan]="obj.templates.length" *ngIf="i == 0">{{obj.name}}</td>
          <td>{{entry.version}}</td>
      </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Comment:  good job my answer is just about reshape the data and simplify the template logic 

Comment: you can use first instead of index it's more a propeate 

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following logic:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black">
    <tr>
        <th>Application</th>
        <th>Version</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let obj of list">
        <td style="border: 1px solid black">{{obj.name}}</td>
        <td>
            <div *ngFor="let entry of obj.templates" style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 2px; margin: 2px">
                {{entry.version}}
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2qbgz) for the same.

Comment: You should surround your templates div with another div that's inline-block and make the name div also inline-block. That way the will be next to eachother and the version underneat eachother.

Comment: Now it looks like a duplicate of mine :S

Comment: @Swoox: Haha; not really though!

Comment: @NicholasK Not sure why stackblitz is compiling this but a `div` is not allowed in a `tr` if you use `ng build--prod` this will break btw.

Comment: I've wrapped the `<div>` inside a `<td>`. It should be okay now.

Comment: @NicholasK I like your way of doing this sometime this easier than calculate the rowspan 

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to do something like this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g4wfud

Only thing you need to is apply your styling.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Application</th>
    <th>Version</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let listItem of list">
    <td style="vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black">{{listItem.name}}</td>
    <td>
      <div *ngFor="let template of listItem.templates" style="border: 1px solid black">
        {{template.version}}
      </div>
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Application</td>
        <td>Version</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of list">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr *ngFor="let sub of item.templates">
                    <td>{{sub.version}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks , do you have a solution with  rowspan  because tables inside table is not recommanded :)

Comment: I will see and let you know. Meanwhile you can use it :)

Answer (score 1):

this just another alternative answer rather make the template logic harder , I just use reduce for map the data to correct structure.

*component*

```
  tableData = []

  ngOnInit() {
      this.tableData = this.list.reduce((result,data) =>{
        const appName=data.name;
        const [first , ...items] = data.templates;

        result.push({appName ,rowSpan : data.templates.length ,version: first.version});
        result.push(...items.map(item=> ({version :item.version})));

        return result;
      },[]) 
  }
```

*template*

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Application</th>
        <th>Version</th>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let data of tableData">
        <td *ngIf="data.rowSpan" [rowSpan]="data.rowSpan">{{data.appName}}</td>
        <td>{{data.version}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jp9pdu)